# include graphic interface on program

Tags: c++, graphics, compiler-errors, include

Like title say, I think i have a problem on one of my include.

I'm studient, my teacher gave me a solution to create a visual interface (coded by himself) named `EZ-Draw`.

But somewhere in my code there is a problem 'cause my compiler tell me many errors of this style:

```
|364|undefined reference to `CreateCompatibleDC@4'|
|559|undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'|
...
```

my code:

*interpreteur.hpp*

```
#ifndef INTERPRETEUR_HPP_INCLUDED
#define INTERPRETEUR_HPP_INCLUDED
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <math.h>
#include "Pile_Template.hpp"
#include "ez-draw++.h"

#define PI 3.14159265

class Interpreteur {
private:
    void (Interpreteur::*ptr)();
    EZWindow myWindow;
    Pile<double> pile;
    Pile<string> pilestr;
    bool run;
public:
    map<string,void(Interpreteur::*)()> myMap;
    Interpreteur();
    ~Interpreteur();
    inline bool getRun() {return run;};
    inline void setEmpilerPile(double nombre) {pile.empiler(nombre);};
    template <typename T>
        string itos(T nombre) // convertit un double en string
        {
            ostringstream ss;
            ss<<nombre;
            return ss.str();
        }
    void addition();
    void moins();
    void multiplie();
    void divise();
    void quit();
    void push();
    void pushstr();
    void pop();
    void popstr();
    void copy();
    void copystr();
    void print();
    void printstr();
    void display();
    void displaystr();
    void count();
    void countstr();
    void swap();
    void swapstr();
    void sinus();
    void cosinus();
    void tangente();
    void racine();
    void trunc();
    void line();
    void color();
    void drawstr();
    void triangle();
    void rectangle();
    void circle();

};
#endif // SOUS_PROGRAMMES_HPP_INCLUDED
```

*interpreteur.cpp*

```
#include "interpreteur.hpp"
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


void Interpreteur::addition()
{
    pile.empiler(pile.depiler()+pile.depiler());
}

void Interpreteur::moins()
{
    double nombre=pile.depiler();
    nombre=pile.depiler()-nombre;
    pile.empiler(nombre);
}

void Interpreteur::multiplie()
{
    pile.empiler(pile.depiler()*pile.depiler());
}

void Interpreteur::divise()
{
    double nombre=pile.depiler();
    nombre=pile.depiler()/nombre;
    pile.empiler(nombre);
}

void Interpreteur::quit()
{
    run=false;
}

void Interpreteur::push()
{
    double i;
    cin>>i;
    pile.empiler(i);
}

void Interpreteur::pushstr()
{
    string chaine;
    char merde;
    cin>>merde;
    if(merde=='"')
    {
        getline(cin,chaine,'"');
        pilestr.empiler(chaine);
    }
    else
    {
        cin.putback(merde);
        cerr<<"mauvaise chaine de caractères"<<endl;
    }
}

void Interpreteur::pop()
{
    pile.depiler();
}

void Interpreteur::popstr()
{
    pilestr.depiler();
}

 void Interpreteur::copy()
{
   int i=pile.depiler();
    pile.empiler(pile[pile.getSommet()-i]);
}

void Interpreteur::copystr()
{
    int i=pile.depiler();
    pilestr.empiler(pilestr[pile.getSommet()-i]);
}

void Interpreteur::print()
{
    cout<<pile.depiler()<<endl;
}

void Interpreteur::printstr()
{
    cout<<pilestr.depiler()<<endl;
}

void Interpreteur::display()
{
    pile.afficher(cout);
}

void Interpreteur::displaystr()
{
    pilestr.afficher(cout);
}

void Interpreteur::count()
{
    pile.empiler(pile.getSommet());
}

void Interpreteur::countstr()
{
    pilestr.empiler(itos(pilestr.getSommet()));
}

void Interpreteur::swap()
{
    double first=pile.depiler();
    double second=pile.depiler();
    pile.empiler(first);
    pile.empiler(second);
}

void Interpreteur::swapstr()
{
    string first=pilestr.depiler();
    string second=pilestr.depiler();
    pilestr.empiler(first);
    pilestr.empiler(second);
}

void Interpreteur::sinus()
{
    pile.empiler(sin(pile.depiler()*PI/180));
}

void Interpreteur::cosinus()
{
    pile.empiler(cos(pile.depiler()*PI/180));
}

void Interpreteur::tangente()
{
    pile.empiler(tan(pile.depiler()*PI/180));
}

void Interpreteur::racine()
{
    pile.empiler(sqrt(pile.depiler()));
}

void Interpreteur::trunc()
{
    int x=pile.depiler();
    pile.empiler(x);
}

void Interpreteur::line()
{
    int y2=pile.depiler();
    int x2=pile.depiler();
    int y1=pile.depiler();
    int x1=pile.depiler();
    myWindow.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
}

void Interpreteur::color()
{
    int couleur=pile.depiler();
    switch(couleur)
    {
        case 1:{myWindow.setColor(ez_black);break;}
        case 2:{myWindow.setColor(ez_red);break;}
        case 3:{myWindow.setColor(ez_green);break;}
        case 4:{myWindow.setColor(ez_blue);break;}
        case 5:{myWindow.setColor(ez_cyan);break;}
        case 6:{myWindow.setColor(ez_magenta);break;}
        case 7:{myWindow.setColor(ez_yellow);break;}
        //pourquoi que on a pas fait le gris ? ez_grey
        default:{pile.empiler(couleur); cerr<<"couleur inconnue"<<endl; break;}
    }
    // COULEUR : ez_black, ez_white, ez_grey, ez_red, ez_green, ez_blue,ez_yellow, ez_cyan, ez_magenta

}

void Interpreteur::drawstr()
{
    string str=pilestr.depiler();
    int y1=pile.depiler();
    int x1=pile.depiler();
    myWindow.drawText(EZ_MC,x1,y1,str);
}

void Interpreteur::triangle()
{
    int y3=pile.depiler();
    int x3=pile.depiler();
    int y2=pile.depiler();
    int x2=pile.depiler();
    int y1=pile.depiler();
    int x1=pile.depiler();
    myWindow.drawTriangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3);
}

void Interpreteur::rectangle()
{
    int y2=pile.depiler();
    int x2=pile.depiler();
    int y1=pile.depiler();
    int x1=pile.depiler();
    myWindow.drawRectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2);
}

void Interpreteur::circle()
{
    int y2=pile.depiler();
    int x2=pile.depiler();
    int y1=pile.depiler();
    int x1=pile.depiler();
    myWindow.drawCircle(x1,y1,x2,y2);
}

Interpreteur::Interpreteur()
{
    run=true;
    myMap["+"]=&Interpreteur::addition;
    myMap["-"]=&Interpreteur::moins;
    myMap["*"]=&Interpreteur::multiplie;
    myMap["/"]=&Interpreteur::divise;
    myMap["exit"]=&Interpreteur::quit;
    myMap["push"]=&Interpreteur::push;
    myMap["pushstr"]=&Interpreteur::pushstr;
    myMap["pop"]=&Interpreteur::pop;
    myMap["popstr"]=&Interpreteur::popstr;
    myMap["copy"]=&Interpreteur::copy;
    myMap["copystr"]=&Interpreteur::copystr;
    myMap["print"]=&Interpreteur::print;
    myMap["printstr"]=&Interpreteur::printstr;
    myMap["display"]=&Interpreteur::display;
    myMap["displaystr"]=&Interpreteur::displaystr;
    myMap["count"]=&Interpreteur::count;
    myMap["countstr"]=&Interpreteur::countstr;
    myMap["swap"]=&Interpreteur::swap;
    myMap["swapstr"]=&Interpreteur::swapstr;
    myMap["sin"]=&Interpreteur::sinus;
    myMap["cos"]=&Interpreteur::cosinus;
    myMap["tan"]=&Interpreteur::tangente;
    myMap["sqrt"]=&Interpreteur::racine;
    myMap["trunc"]=&Interpreteur::trunc;
    myMap["line"]=&Interpreteur::line;
    myMap["color"]=&Interpreteur::color;
    myMap["drawstr"]=&Interpreteur::drawstr;
    myMap["triangle"]=&Interpreteur::triangle;
    myMap["rectangle"]=&Interpreteur::rectangle;
    myMap["circle"]=&Interpreteur::circle;
}

Interpreteur::~Interpreteur()
{
    map<string, void (Interpreteur::*)()>::iterator it;
    myMap.erase(it);
}
```

and here the ["EZ-Draw documentation"](http://www.iut-arles.univ-provence.fr/eremy/EZ-Draw++/EZ-Draw++-0.9.1/) gived by my teacher to understand `ez-draw` and `ez-draw++`

I don't understand what the compiler is trying to tell me

Comment: You may want to edit your account description, "étudiant" in French is spelled "student" in English.

Answer (score 1):

You are using C functions from C++, for this to work you need to explicitly tell the compiler those are C functions. The C header file you are using from C++ should contain those lines to be usable in C++:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

//The header file which declares the functions which are not linked correctly here

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

A bit of explanation:
The function "name mangling" is different for C and C++, since in C++ you can overload a function the name of the function alone does not identify a function uniquely, so the compiler adds some symbols to the names of functions in background when you compile to make those names unique (that's the `DC@4` in `CreateCompatibleDC@4`).

Since your linker expects C++ functions, it searches for `CreateCompatibleDC@4`, but some of your files get compiled in C, and export a function named `CreateCompatible`, that's why you get a "undefined reference": the linker is telling you it can not find the definition of some functions.

Comment: ok, but where I put the code snippet you have wrote just up: `#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" { ... }
#endif `

Comment: At the beginning and at the end of the header file declaring the functions which are giving you error messages.